# Para que serve apply() - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber para que serve a função `apply()` no jquery.

Estou criando um plugin onde estou usando. Por observação vejo que ele pega o `this` e passa como argumento na função `init`. Daí posso usar o `this` ao invés de `opcao` na função.

Mas gostaria de saber de quem conhece, qual a verdadeira função e quando devo usá-lo?

```
(function( $ ){
   var methods = {
        init:function(opcao){
            this.find("input").each(function(i,v){

                console.log(i);
                console.log($(v).appendTo("p"));

            }); 
        },
    }

   $.fn.input = function(method) {      

        console.log(this)
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );

    }; 
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) não é do jQuery mas sim um método muito util e poderoso nativo do JavaScript para chamar uma função mudando-lhe o escopo, e ao mesmo tempo passando argumentos como segundo parâmetro numa array.

Ou seja se tiver esta função:

```
function teste(a, b){
    console.log(this, a, b);
}
```

posso chamar essa função normalmente com `teste(1, 2);` e aí o `this` vai ter o mesmo valor que o `this` no escopo/linha em que invoquei a função.

Mas se usar o `.apply()` os resultados são outros:

```
teste.apply(document.body, ['foo', 'bar'[); // o this refere-se ao document.body
teste.apply(window, [1, 2]); // o this refere-se ao objeto window
```

Nesse teu exemplo quando tens `return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );` o que está a acontecer é que esse método `methods.init` vai ter o mesmo escopo com que `$.fn.input` fôr chamado e passa-lhe os mesmos argumentos. Repara que a palavra reservada `arguments` é uma array com todos os parâmetros com que a função foi chamada.

Comment: Então se eu adicionar parametros na função, no caso o objeto com valores default, eles irão ficar os mesmos. Daí os parâmetros defauts posso deixar dentro do objeto>: methods.  Não precisarei criar outro objeto dentro de $.fn.input .. ATT